# Part of the vertices are not moving correctly when moving root bone

Tags: rigging, vertices

When I move the root bone, part of the vertices-tail area in this case will not move accordingly. I've tried remove the tail vertices from all groups then reassign them to the tail bones, but the problem continues. I also checked in weight paint mode, it seems fine. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I guess we don't know enough about your rigging and weight painting, perhaps share your file